# Pyspark: Parse a column of json strings

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe consisting of one column, called `json`, where each row is a unicode string of json. I'd like to parse each row and return a new dataframe where each row is the parsed json.

```
# Sample Data Frame
jstr1 = u'{"header":{"id":12345,"foo":"bar"},"body":{"id":111000,"name":"foobar","sub_json":{"id":54321,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":20,"col2":"somethong"}}}}'
jstr2 = u'{"header":{"id":12346,"foo":"baz"},"body":{"id":111002,"name":"barfoo","sub_json":{"id":23456,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":30,"col2":"something else"}}}}'
jstr3 = u'{"header":{"id":43256,"foo":"foobaz"},"body":{"id":20192,"name":"bazbar","sub_json":{"id":39283,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":50,"col2":"another thing"}}}}'
df = sql_context.createDataFrame([Row(json=jstr1),Row(json=jstr2),Row(json=jstr3)])
```

I've tried mapping over each row with `json.loads`:

```
(df
  .select('json')
  .rdd
  .map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
  .toDF()
).show()
```

But this returns a `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

I suspect that part of the problem is that when converting from a `dataframe` to an `rdd`, the schema information is lost, so I've also tried manually entering in the schema info:

```
schema = StructType([StructField('json', StringType(), True)])
rdd = (df
  .select('json')
  .rdd
  .map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
)
new_df = sql_context.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
new_df.show()
```

But I get the same `TypeError`.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39380110), it looks like flattening out the rows with `flatMap` might be useful here, but I'm not having success with that either:

```
schema = StructType([StructField('json', StringType(), True)])
rdd = (df
  .select('json')
  .rdd
  .flatMap(lambda x: x)
  .flatMap(lambda x: json.loads(x))
  .map(lambda x: x.get('body'))
)
new_df = sql_context.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
new_df.show()
```

I get this error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Converting a dataframe with json strings to structured dataframe is'a actually quite simple in spark if you convert the dataframe to RDD of strings before (see: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)

For example:

```
>>> new_df = sql_context.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.json))
>>> new_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sub_sub_json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: This is great - Thanks! Is there a way to convert the structtypes to maptypes? Later in my code, I'm parsing out each maptype by `explode`ing the columns.

Comment: Ah I think I've figured it out: I can avoid using maptypes by doing something like this: `body = new_df.select('body').rdd.map(lambda r: r.body).toDF()`

Comment: Actally it's much simpler: just type `new_df.select('body')` and you will have dataframe with body objects only.

Comment: Cool!, is there a way to join the new data frame with the original (which has other fields besides the json string)

Comment: @OphirYoktan Unfortunately not. For this I recommend `from_json` described in the Martin's answer here.

Answer (score 118):

For **Spark 2.1+**, you can use [`from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) which allows the preservation of the other non-json columns within the dataframe as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.json)).schema
df.withColumn('json', from_json(col('json'), json_schema))
```

You let Spark derive the schema of the json string column. Then the `df.json` column is no longer a StringType, but the correctly decoded json structure, i.e., nested `StrucType` and all the other columns of `df` are preserved as-is.

You can access the json content as follows:

```
df.select(col('json.header').alias('header'))
```

Comment: When I try it with streaming data frame (structured streaming), I get an error that Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;\nkafka. Can you please help me how I can use the JSON data from kafka streaming.

Comment: Just use a regular dataframe/rdd to extract the json schema from a batch/sample of data. Then, use the extracted schema in your streaming app.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what is `col` in your code? is it the 'json' column object?

Comment: It's a Spark function which you can import see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col

Comment: Would it be inefficient letting Spark derive the schema of the json?

Comment: Don't understand your question as Spark is deriving the schema here...

Comment: just a 'gotcha' as it gave me some headache: in the part `row.json`, the 'json' is referring to the column named 'json', so if your column is 'my_json' then is going to be `row.my_json` (unhappy choice of column names)

Comment: How does Spark determine the data type of each field when decoding the json structure? Is it safe to leave it to Spark to infer the data types?

Comment: this is actually very helpful when the schema is not known prior reading the file

Answer (score 28):

Existing answers do not work if your JSON is anything but perfectly/traditionally formatted. For example, the RDD-based schema inference expects JSON in curly-braces `{}` and will provide an incorrect schema (resulting in `null` values) if, for example,  your data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1.0,
    "b": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 0.0,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

I wrote a function to work around this issue by sanitizing JSON such that it lives in another JSON object:

```
def parseJSONCols(df, *cols, sanitize=True):
    """Auto infer the schema of a json column and parse into a struct.

    rdd-based schema inference works if you have well-formatted JSON,
    like ``{"key": "value", ...}``, but breaks if your 'JSON' is just a
    string (``"data"``) or is an array (``[1, 2, 3]``). In those cases you
    can fix everything by wrapping the data in another JSON object
    (``{"key": [1, 2, 3]}``). The ``sanitize`` option (default True)
    automatically performs the wrapping and unwrapping.

    The schema inference is based on this
    `SO Post <https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880574)/>`_.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pyspark dataframe
        Dataframe containing the JSON cols.
    *cols : string(s)
        Names of the columns containing JSON.
    sanitize : boolean
        Flag indicating whether you'd like to sanitize your records
        by wrapping and unwrapping them in another JSON object layer.

    Returns
    -------
    pyspark dataframe
        A dataframe with the decoded columns.
    """
    res = df
    for i in cols:

        # sanitize if requested.
        if sanitize:
            res = (
                res.withColumn(
                    i,
                    psf.concat(psf.lit('{"data": '), i, psf.lit('}'))
                )
            )
        # infer schema and apply it
        schema = spark.read.json(res.rdd.map(lambda x: x[i])).schema
        res = res.withColumn(i, psf.from_json(psf.col(i), schema))

        # unpack the wrapped object if needed
        if sanitize:
            res = res.withColumn(i, psf.col(i).data)
    return res
```

Note: `psf` = `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Comment: > For example, the RDD-based schema inference expects JSON in curly-braces

where did you read this? 

awesome find!

Comment: " where did you read this? ". I can't say i read it anywhere, I simply found that pyspark did not parse my JSON unless this was true.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a concise (spark SQL) version of @nolan-conaway's `parseJSONCols` function.

```
SELECT 
explode(
    from_json(
        concat('{"data":', 
               '[{"a": 1.0,"b": 1},{"a": 0.0,"b": 2}]', 
               '}'), 
        'data array<struct<a:DOUBLE, b:INT>>'
    ).data) as data;
```

> PS. I've added the explode function as well :P

You'll need to know some [HIVE SQL types](https://acadgild.com/blog/hive-complex-data-types-with-examples)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def map2json(dict):
    import json
    return json.dumps(dict)
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
spark.udf.register("map2json", lambda dict: map2json(dict), StringType())

spark.sql("select map2json(map('a', '1'))").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the schema of each JSON (and it can be different) you can use :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
 
# ... here you get your DF

# Assuming the first column of your DF is the JSON to parse
my_df = spark.read.json(my_df.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]))
```

Note that it won't keep any other column present in your dataset.
From : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22775

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for added context if your JSON strings are JSON Arrays instead of objects (I can't comment since I don't have rep). If you use [Martin Tapp's solid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880574/13156688) it will return null values for your columns.

**tl;dr**

If your JSON strings are array objects like so:

```
[{"a":1, "b":1.0}]
```

`spark.read.json` will return a dataframe that contains the schema of the *elements* in those arrays and not the include the array itself. `from_json` isn't happy with this, so to be as specific as it wants you can wrap the schema inferred by `spark.read.json` in an `ArrayType` and it will properly parse (instead of returning null values for everything).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

array_item_schema = \
  spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row['json_string_column'])).schema

json_array_schema = ArrayType(array_item_schema, True)

arrays_df = df.select(F.from_json('json_string_column', json_array_schema).alias('json_arrays'))

objects_df = arrays_df.select(F.explode('json_arrays').alias('objects'))
```

### Intro

As an addendum to Nolan Conaway's, it seems that when your JSON is of the form

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1.0,
    "b": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 0.0,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

where the top level object is an array (and not an object), pyspark's `spark.read.json()` treats the array as a collection of objects to be converted into rows instead of a single row.

See example run in PySpark 3.3.0 shell:

```py
>>> myjson        = """[{"a": 1.0,"b": 1},{"a": 2.0,"b": 2}]"""
>>> myotherjson   = """[{"a": 3.0,"b": 3}]"""
>>> rawobjectjson = """{"a": 4.0,"b": 4}"""
>>> spark_read_df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([myjson,myotherjson,rawobjectjson]))
>>> spark_read_df.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|1.0|  1|
|2.0|  2|
|3.0|  3|
|4.0|  4|
+---+---+

>>> spark_read_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

We can see that `myjson` and `myotherjson` which were JSON arrays of JSON objects got expanded to have a row for each object they contained. It also smoothly handled when one of the JSON strings `rawobjectjson` is just a raw object. I think the documentation falls a little short here, as I couldn't find mention of this handling for array objects.

Now let's create a dataframe with a column of JSON strings. Going to drop the `rawobjectjson` because as we'll see `from_json` requires each string to have the same schema (and this *includes* the top level array if present).

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType
>>> json_string_data = [
...     (myjson,),
...     (myotherjson,),
... ]
>>> json_df_schema = StructType([
...     StructField('json_strings', StringType(), True),
... ])
>>> raw_json_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=json_string_data, schema=json_df_schema)
>>> raw_json_df.show()
+--------------------+
|        json_strings|
+--------------------+
|[{"a": 1.0,"b": 1...|
| [{"a": 3.0,"b": 3}]|
+--------------------+
```

Now here's where I tried to use the schema inferred by `spark.read.json` to pass to `from_json` to read the JSON column to objects, **but it kept returning columns that were fully `null`**. As Nolan Conaway mentioned this will happen when the schema passed to `from_json` couldn't be applied to the given strings.

The issue is that in these strings it sees the top level as an array, but as `spark_read_df.printSchema()` shows, the schema inferred by `spark.read.json()` ignores the array level.

#### The Solution

So the solution I ended up going with was just accounting for the top level array in the schema when doing the read.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# This one won't work for directly passing to from_json as it ignores top-level arrays in json strings
# (if any)!
# json_object_schema = spark_read_df.schema()

# from_json is a bit more "simple", it directly applies the schema to the string. In this case
# the top level type is actually an array, so a simple fix is to just wrap the schema that
# spark.read.json returned in an ArrayType to match the true JSON string
json_array_schema = ArrayType(spark_read_df.schema, True)

json_extracted_df = raw_json_df.select(
    F.from_json('json_strings', json_array_schema)
        .alias('json_arrays')
)
```

```py
>>> json_extracted_df.show()
+--------------------+
|         json_arrays|
+--------------------+
|[{1.0, 1}, {2.0, 2}]|
|          [{3.0, 3}]|
+--------------------+

>>> json_extracted_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- json_arrays: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

From there the objects can be pulled out of the array using `pyspark.sql.functions.explode`:

```py
>>> exploded_df = json_extracted_df.select(F.explode('json_arrays').alias('objects'))
>>> exploded_df.show()
+--------+
| objects|
+--------+
|{1.0, 1}|
|{2.0, 2}|
|{3.0, 3}|
+--------+

>>> exploded_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- objects: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I have a use case in which I dont know if the column is an array or not, any solution for that?