# how to Convert JSON String to JSON object in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one of column type of data frame is string but actually it is containing json object of 4 schema where few fields are common. I need to convert that into jason object.

Here is schema of data frame :

> query.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```

value of DF looks like

> query.show(10)

```
+--------------------+
|                test|
+--------------------+
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"Interaction":{"...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"Interaction":{"...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
|{"PurchaseActivit...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

What solution i applied ::

1. write into text file

> query.write.format("text").mode('overwrite').save("s3://bucketname/temp/")

2. read as json

> df = spark.read.json("s3a://bucketname/temp/")

3. now print Schema, It is json string for each row already converted into json object

> df.printSchema()
>
> ```
> root
>  |-- EventDate: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- EventId: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- EventNotificationType: long (nullable = true)
>  |-- Interaction: struct (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- ContextId: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- Created: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- ModelContextId: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- PurchaseActivity: struct (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- BillingCity: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- BillingCountry: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- ShippingAndHandlingAmount: double (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- ShippingDiscountAmount: double (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- SubscriberId: long (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- SubscriptionOriginalEndDate: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- SubscriptionChurn: struct (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- PaymentTypeCode: long (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- PaymentTypeName: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- PreviousPaidAmount: double (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- SubscriptionRemoved: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- SubscriptionStartDate: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- TransactionDetail: struct (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- Amount: double (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- OrderShipToCountry: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- PayPalUserName: string (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- PaymentSubTypeCode: long (nullable = true)
>  |    |-- PaymentSubTypeName: string (nullable = true)
> ```

Is there any best way where i don't need to write dataframe as text file and read it again as json file to get expected output

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41108013/5858851) or perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880574/5858851)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `from_json()` before you write into text file, but you need to define the schema first.

the code look like this :

`data = query.select(from_json("test",schema=schema).alias("value")).selectExpr("value.*")`

`data.write.format("text").mode('overwrite').save("s3://bucketname/temp/")`