# Spark SQL from_json documentation

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Where can I find more detailed information regarding the schema parameter of the from_json function in Spark SQL? A coworker gave me a schema example that works, but to be honest, I just don't understand and it doesn't look like any of the examples I have found thus far. The documentation found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) seems to be lacking.

Answer (score 12):

In the link you shared the `from_json` function uses this example:

```
SELECT from_json('{"a":1, "b":0.8}', 'a INT, b DOUBLE');
```

> Spark SQL supports the vast majority of Hive features such as the [defining TYPES](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/compatibility/hive.html)

The example problem I was facing required me to parse the following JSON object:

```
{'data': [
    {
       "id":02938, 
       "price": 2938.0, 
       "quantity": 1
    }, 
    {
       "id":123, 
       "price": 123.5, 
       "quantity": 2
    }
]}
```

The corresponding Spark SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    from_json('{"data":[{"id":123, "quantity":2, "price":39.5}]}'), 
    'data array<struct<id:INT, quantity:INT, price:DOUBLE>>').data) AS product_details;
```

> you can couple this with the `explode` function to extract each element into it's own column.

I recommend this [post](https://acadgild.com/blog/hive-complex-data-types-with-examples) to learn more about constructing the types for your query.

Refer to this SO post for more examples
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55432107/1500443

Comment: The example gives an error
IndentationError: unexpected indent

this works: 

SELECT 
    from_json(
    '{"data":[{"id":123, "quantity":2, "price":39.5}]}', 
    'data array<struct<id:INT, quantity:INT, price:DOUBLE>>') AS product_details;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pass your JSON to the `schema_of_json` function to get the schema, so I use this to get the right schema regardless of the JSON:

```sql
SELECT from_json(col, schema_of_json(col))
```

In your case you'll also want to add `map('allowNumericLeadingZeros', 'true')` to both function calls, so:

```sql
SELECT from_json(
    col,
    schema_of_json(col, map('allowNumericLeadingZeros', 'true')),
    map('allowNumericLeadingZeros', 'true')
  )
```

Comment: When you run this you don't get an `AnalysisException: Schema should be specified in DDL format as a string literal or output of the schema_of_json/schema_of_csv functions instead of schema_of_json(col)` ?  What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: This SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106480/how-to-resolve-this-sql-error-of-schema-of-json suggests that this doesn't work.  I'm super curious under what conditions you make it work.

Comment: I was using Spark version 2.something. Don't know if it works on newer versions.