# How to resolve this sql error of schema_of_json

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I need to find out the schema of a given JSON file, I see sql has schema_of_json [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html)
and something like this works flawlessly

```
> SELECT schema_of_json('[{"col":0}]');
 ARRAY<STRUCT<`col`: BIGINT>>
```

But if I query for my table name, it gives me the following error

```
>SELECT schema_of_json(Transaction) as json_data from table_name;
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'schemaofjson(`Transaction`)' due to data type mismatch: The input json should be a string literal and not null; however, got `Transaction`.; line 1 pos 7;
```

The Transaction is one of the columns in my table and after checking it manually I can attest that it is of String type(json).

The SQL statement has it to give me the schema of the JSON, how to do it?

Comment: looks like the column "Transaction" contain some `null` values. You may try `SELECT schema_of_json(Transaction) as json_data from table_name where Transaction is not null;`

Comment: That did not work still, the same error is shown. Like I said the Transaction column is a string not `null`

Comment: Can you share a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

after looking further into the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.schema_of_json.html) that it is clear that the word `foldable` means that of the static one, and a column from a table JSON won't work

for minimal reroducible example here you go:

`SELECT schema_of_json(CAST('{ "a": "b" }' AS STRING))`

As soon as the cast is introduced in the above statement, the schema_of_json will fail......... It needs a static JSON as it's input