# Read a jsonb type field in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a table I am reading from Postres db and one of those fields is a jsonb type field that contains a nested array. The array can change at the row level within the table in Postgres, meaning the number of keys/value pairs can change. Inferring the schema sets the field to a string type. Does Pyspark support jsonb type fields and infer the schema for the field type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: [Pyspark: Parse a column of json strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107835/pyspark-parse-a-column-of-json-strings)

It took the jsonb field, parsed the field names, and restructured the df to accommodate for the nested array.