# Spark: How to parse and transform json string from spark data frame rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to parse and transform json string from spark dataframe rows in pyspark?

I'm looking for help how to parse:

- json string to json struct `output 1`
- transform json string to columns a, b and id `output 2`

Background: I get via API  json strings with a large number of rows (`jstr1`, `jstr2`, ...), which are saved to spark `df`. I can read schema for each row separately, but this is not the solution as it is very slow as schema has a large number of rows. Each `jstr` has the same schema, columns/keys a and b stays the same, just `id` and values in columns change.

EDIT: blackbishop solution to use MapType schema works like a charm `schema = "map<string, array<struct<a:int,b:int>>>"`

Question was extended to:
[How to transform JSON string with multiple keys, from spark data frame rows in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970584/how-to-transform-json-string-with-multiple-keys-from-spark-data-frame-rows-in-p)

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
jstr1 = '{"id_1": [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]}'
jstr2 = '{"id_2": [{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 7, "b": 8}]}'
    
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(json=jstr1),Row(json=jstr2)])
    
schema = F.schema_of_json(df.select(F.col("json")).take(1)[0].json)
df2 = df.withColumn('json', F.from_json(F.col('json'), schema))
df2.show()
```

Current output:

```
+--------------------+
|                json|
+--------------------+
|[[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]  |
|                  []|
+--------------------+
```

Required output 1:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|         json      |   id   |
+--------------------+-------+
|[[[1, 2], [3, 4]]] |   id_1 |
|[[[5, 6], [7, 8]]] |   id_2 |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Required output 2:

```
+---------+----------+-------+
|    a    |     b    |   id  |
+--------------------+-------+
|    1    |    2     |  id_1 |
|    3    |    4     |  id_1 |
|    5    |    6     |  id_2 |
|    7    |    8     |  id_2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you specify the json rows output that you get from an api call in the question? or Do you get a single json string in one api call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: Parse a column of json strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107835/pyspark-parse-a-column-of-json-strings)

Comment: @Chris this doesn't answer the question as MapType schema must be used to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting null for the second row because you're using only the schema of the first row which is different from the second one. You can parse the JSON to a MapType instead, where the keys are of type string and values of type array of structs :

```
schema = "map<string, array<struct<a:int,b:int>>>"

df = df.withColumn('json', F.from_json(F.col('json'), schema))

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- json: map (nullable = true)
# |    |-- key: string
# |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
```

Then, with some simple transformations, you get the expected outputs:

- The `id` column represents the key in the map, you get it with `map_keys` function
- The structs `<a:int, b:int>` represents the values that you get using `map_values` function

```py
output1 = df.withColumn("id", F.map_keys("json").getItem(0)) \
            .withColumn("json", F.map_values("json").getItem(0))

output1.show(truncate=False)

# +----------------+----+
# |json            |id  |
# +----------------+----+
# |[[1, 2], [3, 4]]|id_1|
# |[[5, 6], [7, 8]]|id_2|
# +----------------+----+

output2 = output1.withColumn("attr", F.explode("json")) \
    .select("id", "attr.*")

output2.show(truncate=False)

# +----+---+---+
# |id  |a  |b  |
# +----+---+---+
# |id_1|1  |2  |
# |id_1|3  |4  |
# |id_2|5  |6  |
# |id_2|7  |8  |
# +----+---+---+
```