# JSON parse in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

In a table having 2 columns(my_col and ID) with many records, below are 2 sample records

Record 1 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `A123`

Record 2 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"ZZZ":["333"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `B222`

Need to flatten using pyspark:

| Key | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 | A123 |
| XXX | 456 | A123 |
| YYY | 246 | A123 |
| YYY | 135 | A123 |
| ZZZ | 333 | B222 |

Can you please help on this issue?

FYI... Achieved the result in Hive:

```
select split(element,':')[0] key,
       e.value,
       id
from
(
SELECT 
 regexp_replace(e.element,'^\\{|"| *\\[|\\]|\\}$','') element, 
 t.id 
FROM
    input_df t
    lateral view explode(split(my_col,'(?<=\\]) *, *(?=\\")')) e as element 
)s lateral view explode(split(split(element,':')[1],',')) e as value
```

Comment: Have you tried using [from_json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107835/pyspark-parse-a-column-of-json-strings)?

Comment: @Nick Odell - No. Can you please share the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is casting the JSON column into a `map` and explode all values until flat it

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


input_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ['A123', '{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}'],
  ['B222', '{"ZZZ":["333"]}']
], schema='id string, my_col string')

output_df = (input_df
             .withColumn('entries', f.from_json('my_col', 'map<string, array<string>>'))
             .select('id', f.explode('entries'))
             .select('ID', 'Key', f.explode('value').alias('Value')))

output_df.show(truncate=False)
+----+---+-----+
|ID  |Key|Value|
+----+---+-----+
|A123|XXX|123  |
|A123|XXX|456  |
|A123|YYY|246  |
|A123|YYY|135  |
|B222|ZZZ|333  |
+----+---+-----+
```

Comment: Getting ERROR from dataframe input_df.                                                                                 Error:  raise ValueError("Could not parse datatype: %s" % s)                                                              ValueError: Could not parse datatype:ID String, json_col String

Comment: Which version are you using? I did it on Spark 3