# Extract data from JSON in Pyspark Dataframe from a column and Flatten

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, json-flattener

I have a pyspark dataframe with a nested JSON column in a string format.

The output likes like:
[image]

I was trying to flatten it into row and column format using PySpark.

Any suggestions or clues would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html?highlight=from_json#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: Parse a column of json strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107835/pyspark-parse-a-column-of-json-strings)

Comment: Hi Steven,
Nope, it doesn't