Create dataframe from Nested JSON
I have the below json
[{"Name":"Tom","Age":"40","Account":"savings","address": {
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY"
        }}]

Now I need to create dataframe using spark from this JSON with below structure
Name Age Account city state

Below is code I am using
schema2= StructType([
    StructField("TICKET", StringType(), True),
    StructField("TRANFERRED", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ACCOUNT", StringType(), True),
    StructField("address", StructType([StructField('city', StringType(), True), StructField('state', StringType(), True)]), True),
])

path='dbfs:/FileStore/new.json'
df = spark.read.schema(schema2).option("multiLine", True).json(path)

And I am getting below structure

What schema change should be done to flatten the inner json as columns ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107835/pyspark-parse-a-column-of-json-strings

@darthbaba I have checked, where we can use from_json to convert json string to struct type, but need to understand how I can convert structtype to columns
in this case city and state respectively

Please check the below code
flattened_df = df.select(
    col("Name"),
    col("Age"),
    col("Account"),
    col("address.city").alias("city"),
    col("address.state").alias("state")
)

